# What is this CDN in NFT marketplace ? it this the replacement for IPFS.? any leads or links related to the same would be great help

Tags: nft, ipfs, meta-data

I would like to know what exactly this CDN is?
I know that we can deploy and publish the metadata through IPFS. But would like to know the alternatives for it and recently came across this CDN. Since I am not familiar with the term 'CDN' asking you the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDN is content delivery network. It is a way of delivering content of HTTP/S protocol - your usual internet. It is an internet standard and used commonly for usual internet technologies. IPFS is a decentralized CDN, AWS S3 is a centralized CDN. Please make sure to do a simple online search, this might seem intimidating at first, but is simpler than you imagine!